# searching multi-word patterns from one file in another using awk

Tags: bash, design-patterns, awk

patterns file:

```
wicked liquid
movie
guitar
balance transfer offer
drive car
```

bigfile file:

```
wickedliquidbrains
drivelicense
balanceofferings
```

using awk on command line:

```
awk '/balance/ && /offer/' bigfile
```

i get the result i want which is

```
balanceofferings

awk '/wicked/ && /liquid/' bigfile
```

gives me

```
wickedliquidbrains, which is also good..


awk '/drive/ && /car/' bigfile
```

does not give me drivelicense which is also good, as i am having &&

now when trying to pass shell variable, containg those '/regex1/ && /regex2/.. etc' to awk..

```
awk -v search="$out" '$0 ~ search' "$bigfile"
```

awk does not run.. what may be the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk "$out" "$bigfile"
```

When you do `$0 ~ search`, the value of `search` has to be a regular expression. But you were setting it to a string containing a bunch of regexps with `&&` between them -- that's not a valid regexp.

To perform an action on the lines that match, do:

```
awk "$out"' { /* do stuff */ }' "$bigfile"
```

I switched from double quotes to single quotes for the action in case the action uses awk variables with `$`.

Comment: thank you Barmar, even though i found it myself the same.. few minutes ago :)), anyway still dont understand why the variable passing method isn't working. Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't work because `/foo/ && /bar/` is not a regular expression. It doesn't just substitue the value into the line, it uses it as a value in an expression.

Comment: how would i concat now into this, to show line numbers where there is a match.. so it would be /foo/ && /bar/ { print NR, $0 }, but how to concat them in that bash script. THanks

Comment: sorry.. it works.. i missviewed no space after "$out" and ' {

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

An alternative to Barmars's solution with arguments passed with `-v`:

```
awk -v search="$out" 'match($0,search)' "$bigfile"
```

Test:

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo"|awk -v luk=one 'match($0,luk)'
one
```

Passing two (real) regexs (EREs) to [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
echo -e "one\ntwo\nnone"|awk -v re1=^o -v re2=e$ 'match($0,re1) && match($0,re2)'
```

Output:

```
one
```

If You want to read the pattern_file and do match against all the rows, You could try something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{N=NR;re[N,0]=split($0,a);for(i in a)re[N,i]=a[i];next}
{
  for(i=1;i<=N;++i) {
    #for(j=1;j<=re[i,0]&&match($0,re[i,j]);++j);
    for(j=1;j<=re[i,0]&&$0~re[i,j];++j);
    if(j>re[i,0]){print;break}
  }
}' patterns_file bigfile
```

Output:

```
wickedliquidbrains
```

At the 1st line it reads and stores the pattern_file in a 2D array `re`. Each row contains the split input string. The 0th element of each row is the length of that row.
Then it reads `bigfile`. Each lines of `bigfile` are tested for match of `re` array. If all items in a row are matching then that row is printed.

Comment: but that way you could not pass two regexes at the time with &&, which is main task of my question or you could?

Comment: @branquito: Sure, you can! You can `&&` and `||` any number of `match` functions. I extended my answer.

Comment: well yes like that, but you see the reason for passing them as shell variable is that they were constructed from array elements, while reading from file line by line, so.. sometime there will be two of them, sometime three maybe four.. so what i did is, i read line, split by words putting them into an array, than itterating through that array and concatenating them together with && in between, so that i get /word1/ && /word2/ etc.. all that is now a shell variable holding one string representing what should be passed as a rule to awk.. maybe i am more clear now..

Comment: anyway i like your solution for some other cases, where it prooves to be useful.. thanks!

Comment: @branquito: The problem is that Your question was not that. And You accepted an answer which does not really solves your problem. My original answer was just an extension of that answer. But if I understood your needs, this [tag:awk] script does what you need.